# Check Comments/Javadoc number of words with Checkstyle

Tags: java, comments, javadoc, checkstyle

Is it possible to set up a checkstyle rule that will count the number of words from a commment and then shows a problem if the number of words is under a defined limit. I searched on the checkstyle [Javadoc](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html) properties, but did not found something useful.

For Example:

```
/**
 * Stores the database connection.
 */
private Connection mConnection;
```

The comment contains more  than 3  words and would be correct. But if the number of words would be under the limit, checkstyle should mark it as a problem.

If this is possible, it would be great if the rule is applied to every part of a comment (description of return, the parameters, method description and so on).

Comment: Don't try. This kind of check can only be performed by a human being. It will never lead to better docs unless you educate the developers and manually inspect the documentation. My two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a standard Checkstyle check to do that.  However you could write your own:

- The ["Writing Checks"](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) page provides an introduction.
- You could use the source code for the classes in the `...checks.javadoc` [package](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/package-frame.html) to help you understand how to deal with comments.

---

Comment: word count is not a valid measure of javadoc quality.  It is not bad style to have terse or minimal descriptions for things whose meaning is blatantly self-evident in the context.  Besides, counting words is only going to encourage people to pad out their javadocs with useless or meaningless stuff; e.g "yadda, yadda, yadda" :-).

If you want to make a meaningful assessment of javadoc quality, a human being needs to read them.

Comment: I reconsiderd the original idea and i guess you two are right. I will focus more on code reviews rather than counting words, which will only give a statement about the quantity.